# How can I properly pass webdriver around when trying to run tests in parallel?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nunit-3.0

My work has tasked us with writing an automation framework that encompasses selenium webdriver with c# / nunit. We're currently using nunit 3.0. My original idea was to extract enough of the framework stuff out so that the teams who would use the framework wouldn't have to worry about stuff such as setting up / tearing down webdriver.

We decided to go the route of having a test helper class that has a setup / teardown that would instantiate driver based on a config setting (chrome, ie, etc.) and then tear it down after each test. We also added a protected class driver variable that gets set whenever setup is called. This way, every test class can extend TestHelper and they can get driver for free.

This works perfectly when we're not running tests in parallel but as soon as we start doing parallel tests then driver gets overwritten each time (which makes sense).

My question is, is there a better way that we could be doing this such that it keeps the original idea of having driver available in TestHelper and keeping a lot of driver manipulation out of the tests themselves. I'm really wanting to not have driver declarations / initializations in each test and just keep the test suites to test specific code.

Here are some test classes that resemble whats happening (I couldn't actually post the production code because work is funny about that):

Here is my test helper class:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

namespace AutomationTest
{
    class TestHelper
    {

        protected IWebDriver driver;

        [SetUp]
        public void startBrowser()
        {
            driver = new ChromeDriver("C:\\Users\\james\\Desktop");
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void closeBrowser()
        {
            driver.Close();
            driver.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my test class (8 tests just to test parallel testing):

```
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace AutomationTest 
{
    [TestFixture]
    [Parallelizable(ParallelScope.All)]
    class ParallelTest : TestHelper
    {
        [Test]
        public void test1()
        {            
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
            Assert.AreEqual(driver.Title, "Google", "Stuff didn't work");
        }

        [Test]
        public void test2()
        {            
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
            Assert.AreEqual(driver.Title, "Google", "Stuff didn't work");
        }

        [Test]
        public void test3()
        {            
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
            Assert.AreEqual(driver.Title, "Google", "Stuff didn't work");
        }

        [Test]
        public void test4()
        {            
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
            Assert.AreEqual(driver.Title, "Google", "Stuff didn't work");
        }

        [Test]
        public void test5()
        {            
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
            Assert.AreEqual(driver.Title, "Google", "Stuff didn't work");
        }

        [Test]
        public void test6()
        {           
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
            Assert.AreEqual(driver.Title, "Google", "Stuff didn't work");
        } 

        [Test]
        public void test7()
        {            
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
            Assert.AreEqual(driver.Title, "Google", "Stuff didn't work");
        }

        [Test]
        public void test8()
        {            
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
            Assert.AreEqual(driver.Title, "Google", "Stuff didn't work");   
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace AutomationTest 
{
class TestHelper
{

    //protected IWebDriver driver;
    protected void Browse(Action<IWebDriver> action)
    {
      var driver = new ChromeDriver("C:\\Users\\james\\Desktop");
      action(driver);
      driver.Close();
      driver.Quit();
    }
    [SetUp]
    public void startBrowser()
    {
        // driver = new ChromeDriver("C:\\Users\\james\\Desktop");
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void closeBrowser()
    {
        // driver.Close();
        // driver.Quit();
    }
}

[TestFixture]
[Parallelizable(ParallelScope.All)]
class ParallelTest : TestHelper
{
    [Test]
    public void test1()
    {   
        Browse( (driver) => {         
          driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
          Assert.AreEqual(driver.Title, "Google", "Stuff didn't work");
        });
    }

    [Test]
    public void test2()
    {   
        Browse( (driver) => {                  
          driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
          Assert.AreEqual(driver.Title, "Google", "Stuff didn't work");
        });
    }

    [Test]
    public void test3()
    {     
        Browse( (driver) => {                
          driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
          Assert.AreEqual(driver.Title, "Google", "Stuff didn't work");
        });
    }

    [Test]
    public void test4()
    {     
        Browse( (driver) => {                
          driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
          Assert.AreEqual(driver.Title, "Google", "Stuff didn't work");
        });
    }

    [Test]
    public void test5()
    {       
        Browse( (driver) => {              
          driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
          Assert.AreEqual(driver.Title, "Google", "Stuff didn't work");
        });
    }

    [Test]
    public void test6()
    {     
        Browse( (driver) => {               
          driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
          Assert.AreEqual(driver.Title, "Google", "Stuff didn't work");
        });
    } 

    [Test]
    public void test7()
    {     
        Browse( (driver) => {                
          driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
          Assert.AreEqual(driver.Title, "Google", "Stuff didn't work");
        });
    }

    [Test]
    public void test8()
    {     
        Browse( (driver) => {                
          driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
          Assert.AreEqual(driver.Title, "Google", "Stuff didn't work");   
        });
    }
}
}
```

This will instantiate a new driver for each test which is fine since you need separate browser drivers and browser instances in order for your tests to run in parallel and not interfere.

Comment: Thanks Cosmin! I'm trying to test this out and it's yelling because the Browse method doesn't return anything. Am I missing something?

Comment: Perfect, thank you sir :) I'll mark it as answered once I figure out how lol.

Comment: Are you really going to put 100 lines of test code into a single method call? That is going to be a nightmare to debug, etc.

Comment: What method has 100 lines? I have it split into 2 classes: test helper and the actual test suite class.

Comment: If you use Page Object model, your test code is distributed across your page objects, and your test methods will contain main orchestration flow. You can further abstract that into Steps/Scenario classes and reduce your top-level code to few lines which will just invoke a specific test scenario. In short, you don't have to write everything in that action lambda.

Comment: I'm talking about a real script for an actual test case, not just a one-liner that browses to google.com and then an assert. A real test case, at least any that I've written, are 50+ lines of code.. and I do use the page object model. I've worked on eCommerce sites and banking apps and even with the POM they are that long. The method call I'm referring to is `Browse()`.